# Branching in TFS

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I have a web application (C# and Angular). There are two folders called "Views" and "Resources" which will be different for each customer. I would like to have them all under TFS. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how to add sources in TFS and branch them? or asking a suitable branch hierarchy of your situation.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT: I'm asking for the right strategy to handle the situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a  single set of Views and Resources that excersize the functionality that you are building for all customers.

You should use an automated  build to package your vanilla site and deploy it to your development server continuously. Ideally you should package your vanilla site as a zip or Nuget package.

Then, in a  separate folder (TFVC) or Repo (Git), you create a resource/view  set for a customer. Have your solution pull the packaged vanilla site and unpack it (so  it'snot under source control here) and  let'syou run the site for development.

Package and publish each customers customisations along with the vanilla site.

Now when you go to ship to a customer you can have a script that pulls the vanilla+customer packages  and  deployes the site.

If you want you can publish the bits to a known and  accessible location and have your site self update.

You might also leverage the release management tools to deploy.

Comment: Excellent @mrhinsh